# Grails Can't Update Row with id name other than id

Tags: grails

I am attempting to use Grails to manage a preexisting table in our Microsoft SQL database. The issue is that the table does not have a int ID column. What it has as a primary key is String field.

In my domain class, I have the following code, which should make this work:

```
static mapping = {
        id name: "myPK", generator: "assigned", column: "myPK"
        version false
    }
```

And this is the update function:

```
@Transactional
    def update(MyDomain myDomain) {
        if (myDomain== null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (myDomain.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond myDomain.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        myDomain.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'myDomain.label', default: 'MyDomain'), myDomain.myPK])
                redirect myDomain
            }
            '*'{ respond myDomain, [status: OK] }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I haven't really changed it much from what is generated, aside from replacing id with 'myPK'. I have also tried this without replacing id.

This is the error message I get:

```
MyDomain not found with id myString
```

I am also having issue creating a new one, in that it acts like it saved the new entry, but cannot redirect to it and it does not exist in the database. I am to select from it, though, and see all entries.

I am using Grails 3.1.1

Please tell me if there is any other code you would like to see.

**Edit 1**

Here's the full domain class:

```
class MyDomain{

    String myPK
    Character prop1
    Character prop2
    Character prop3
    Character prop4
    Character prop5
    Character prop6
    Character prop7
    Character prop8
    Character prop9
    Character prop10
    Character prop11
    Date prop12
    Character prop13

    static mapping = {
        id name: "myPK", generator: "assigned", column: "myPK"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        myPKmaxSize: 10
        prop1 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop2 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop3 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop4 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop5 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop6 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop7 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop8 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop9 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop10 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop11 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        prop12 nullable: true
        prop13 nullable: true, maxSize: 1
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**
Here is the save function that I am using to create a new entry of the domain class:

```
    @Transactional
    def save(MyDomain myDomain) {
        if (myDomain== null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (myDomain.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond myDomain.errors, view:'create'
            return
        }

        myDomain.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'myDomain.label', default: 'MyDomain'), myDomain.myPK])
                redirect myDomain
            }
            '*' { respond myDomain, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of your Domain, specifically the properties. Also, can you show how you are new-ing up a domain?

Comment: I added the whole domain class. What do you mean by new-ing up a domain? If you mean how did I create it, then the answer is that I used db-reverse-engineer.

Comment: I'm focusing on this part of your question, "I am also having issue creating a new one, in that it acts like it saved the new entry, but cannot redirect to it and it does not exist in the database."
So when you create a new one, what are you doing? `def myDomain = new MyDomain()`? Are you setting any properties either with key:value pairs in the constructor or after you have newed it up?

Comment: I added the code for the save function inside of my controller. I should also note that I am able to show an already created entry by referencing the myPK property using the default show function with a link that I create.
The link is something like this `localhost:8080/show/myString`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm starting to see how this is all fitting together.

Comment: Can you post your DB table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting Bryan G Campbell's answer with no luck, I decided to add an id column to the table, which fixed problem. I made sure to make the column big int and null and gave all previous entries a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a Grails Domain always has an `id` property. I don't believe you can give it a different name, such as `myPK`. If you could, all the dynamic methods would be named wrong, ie: `findAllById()` would not exist. You can type it as a String and map it to any DB column you want by:

```
class MyDomain {
    String id
    ...
    static mapping = {
        id column: 'myPK', generator: 'assigned'
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want a property named `myPk`, you can create a transient in your domain:

```
    ...
    static transients = ['myPk']
    String getMyPK(){
        return id
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I noticed I had missed a rename in my domain class I posted, which I corrected. If you notice, I am already doing that first part in my domain class, unless the column attribute must go first in the mapping.

Comment: I went ahead and attempted to emulate your example for the domain class, but it keeps trying to alter the table to have `myPK`, even though I removed all references to it. Also, the index page no longer loads, saying that 'myPK' does not exist. I removed all references to it in the index page and the controller.

Comment: I thought your MS Sql DB had a `varchar` primary key column named `myPK`. Thus the mapping maps the `myDomain.id` property to the SQLTableName.myPK SQL column.
I feel like we are not understanding each other correctly. If you go back to what you originally had, but just change `String myPK` in your domain to `String id` and also remove `name:'myPK` from your `mapping` closure, `id` line. It should work for you.

Comment: If you want me to look at your code, I'd be happy to. Maybe by seeing the whole think I can spot the mistake. If that would help, let me know and we can find a way to connect.

Comment: I did do what you suggested, which has now broken the application. And yeah, I can send you the code.

Comment: Sorry for sending you backwards in functionality. You can zip it up and email it to me at bryangcampbell at gmail dot com.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130256/discussion-between-bryan-g-campbell-and-justin-foley).